# npm > 3 (3.3.2) still nesting modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

when I try to use the node module ember-giftwrap, I get this error:

> Installing packages for tooling via npm...C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(312,5):
>   error MSB3491: In die Datei "
>   Release\obj\bufferutil\bufferutil.tlog\bufferutil.lastbuildstate"
>   konnten keine Zeilen geschrieben werden. Der angegebe ne Pfad und/oder
>   Dateiname ist zu lang. Der vollständig qualifizierte Dateiname muss
>   kürzer als 260 Zeichen und der Pfa dname kürzer als 248 Zeichen sein.
>   [D:\asdf\node_modules\ember-giftwrap\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\testem\node
>       _modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\
>   build\bufferutil.vcxproj]

At the end of the message you can see a path with nested node_modules. So I've seen these problems should be fixed with higher versions of npm. I've upgraded npm with npm-windows-upgrade to Version 3.3.2 and tried again, but I still get the same error.

Just for the the record, I really don't know much about npm or node, just a few tutorials so far. Unfortunately I am forced to use it to continue the development of our application. I am fighting errors like this since the beginning of playing around with ember-cli on windows machines, wasted days on figuring out what versions of node and python (64 or x86 etc.) are good. This is not just PITA, it is an economic desaster!

**Update:**
not just the ember-giftwrap throws that error. All Projects created with ember-cli are generating too deep nested node_modules inside the project path. Is this a npm problem or a ember-cli problem?

Comment: I can't understand German, but it looks like `node-gyp` build failed for `bufferutil` module. [Make sure you have](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) python `2.x` and Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 installed on your machine.

Comment: I have python 2.7 and Visual Studio 2015 installed. VS is installed completely, so it should everything be there?

Comment: I'm not completely sure that `node-gyp` supports VS-2015.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/555), `node-gyp` versions prior to `2.x.x` have no support for VS-2015.

Comment: I try to install all python requirements at the moment, but what is about the nested modules problem?

Comment: Try removing your `node_modules` directory and reinstalling all dependencies with npm `3.x`. It should flatten everything (didn't test it).